# deployment from programming cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Can anybody help.  I can't get the simplest notebook (see code below) to deploy.  I upload the notebook to my Wolfram Cloud account.  Click deploy.  Copy the link and send it to my sister.  She can move the sliders but the graphs don't update.  I tried with SaveDefinitions True and also with False.   Is anybody deploying anything successfully?  Besides the fact that everything is super slow, and the server often doesn't respond, a simple deployment doesn't seem to work.  If she does shift-enter she gets a no-permission error.

Is there a step by step guide to deploying?  And what is the difference really between Mathematica Online and Wolfram Programming Cloud?

Or maybe I should ask the question this way....  I create simple highschool level notebooks in Mathematica desktop.  They work fine.  I want to share them with other people who don't have or want the CDF player.  What is the best way?

```
myColorScheme="SouthwestColors"
myBrown=ColorData[myColorScheme][6/30];
myGreen=ColorData[myColorScheme][25/30];
myBlue=ColorData[myColorScheme][30/30];
myYellow=ColorData[myColorScheme][17/30];
Manipulate[theSlope=a  Cos [ thePointX];
  Plot[{theSlope (x-thePointX) + a Sin [thePointX]+7,a Cos [x ],a Sin [x ] +7}, {x,0, 2Pi},
  PlotRange->{{0,7},{-4,11}},
  PlotLabel->Style["Slope of Tangent Line =\n"<>ToString[N[a Cos[thePointX]]]<>"\n\n",
  Italic,FontSize->18],
  Epilog->{Red,PointSize[.02],Point[{thePointX,a Cos[thePointX]}],Point[{thePointX,
  a Sin[thePointX]+7}]}, AspectRatio->1], 
  {{a,1,"amplitude"}, 1,3,1,Appearance->"Labeled"},
  {{thePointX,1,"point"},0, 2 Pi},SaveDefinitions->True]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.